# Java JFrame Initialization

Tags: java, jframe

In Java, is JFrame j; a valid initialization statement?  I'm just starting out and trying to learn the ins and outs, and my instructor wants us to get better at using shorter code by truncating certain initialization statements/variable declarations.

Comment: Well, it compiles.  Depending on how you reference it in your method it may give you an error around it not being initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having just that line doesn't initalise the variable. It needs to be something like this:

```
private JFrame j = null; // Possible to be initalised later on in your code
```

or

```
private JFrame j = new JFrame(); // Initalised when declared.
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a valid definition.

It says that there is an instance named `j` which is of type `JFrame`.

It does not hold a instance though. Trying to reference `j` would give a `NullPointerException`. You would need to at least initialize it at some point:

```
JFrame j;
...
j = new JFrame();
```

-or-

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
```

Answer (score 1):

> is `JFrame j;` a valid initialization statement?

No because this is not initialization but declaration statement where you declare reference of type `JFrame` but you don't initialize it with any value yet.

To initialize it you need to set its value to `null` or to object of type JFrame. To create instance of class you need to use `new` operator which will create object of class you want and return reference to this new object. So initialization can look like

```
JFrame f = null; // initialized with null
JFrame j = new JFrame(); //i nitialized with JFrame object
```

or

```
JFrame j; // not initialized yet
j = new JFrame(); // now initialized with JFrame object
```